# spoofing request method in laravel action() helper method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, http-delete

In a Laravel 5.5 project, I have a student controller with `destory` method.

```
public function destroy(Student $student)
{
    //destroy $student and redirect
}
```

I have the route for the controller as follows

```
Route::delete('/student/{id}', 'StudentController@destroy');
```

Now let's get to the question.

I have a page to manage students and it has a delete button.

```
  <a class="btn btn-danger"
       href="{{ action('StudentController@destroy', ['id' => $student->id]) }}" >
  Delete
  </a>
```

when i click the delete button it throws `method not allowed exception` since the request is not a delete request. **Is there any way/workaround to specify/spoof the request method through `action()/route()` helper functions?**

Normally I would have created a form with a hidden `_method="delete"` input and post the form. but if I am adding an update button, then I would have to create another form with a hidden `_method="patch"` in it and I don't think this is a good practice.

please give some ideas to go forward.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question - yes, you should create form that will allow you to delete the student. This is how REST should be used - you don't create workarounds but you just use valid HTTP method for given action.

There is also one other reason why you shouldn't use links and GET methods for this. For example let's assume your URL to remove student looks like this:

```
http://example.com/students/1/delete
```

When you type url in browser, browsers usually remember previous urls, so you could remove some student by mistake if you used GET method to remove students.

Of course in above example you could use JavaScript that will be launched when you click the link that will run valid HTTP action, but it might mean more work than using simple form.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that I can think of it:

1. Create a form with method DELETE

   ```
   {!! Form::model($student, ['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['StudentController@destroy', $student->id]]) !!}
       {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
   ```
2. Create an ajax request with request type DELETE

   ```
   $.ajax({
      url: '/students/'+id+'/delete,
      type: "DELETE",
      data:{ _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" }
   });
   ```

Comment: ajax way is fine. but this means we can't spoof HTTP verbs using `action` or `route` methods right?

Comment: Yes. It's always a get if you make a simple <a href=""> link. Only with ajax and form way you can spoof the method